# Disabling the radio button with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a group of radio buttons with same `name` and some of which may be disabled. I don't want the user to check or uncheck the disabled radio buttons . Obviously this means that if the checked radio button in the group is disabled the user cannot change the selection.

i wrote the following code for this.

```
$("#container").delegate(":radio","click",function(e){
    alert($(":radio").filter(":checked").val());
    //this always shows up the value of the radio button clicked
    if($(":radio").filter(":checked").is(":disabled"))
    {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

});
```

I suppose the problem is that as soon as the radio button is clicked the selection changes and the event handler is executed and `.preventDefault()` reverts the selection.

I hope it's clear

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dTBVa/3/)

Comment: disabled radio buttons already arent clickable in the first place so why do you need jquery to duplicate that functionality?

Comment: Does the click event fire when you click a disabled radio button? I dont think so.

Comment: ah i see hwat you mean now. if a radio button in the SAME GROUP is disabled, other buttons are still clickable. then in jquery what you do is just disable the whole radio group with any disabled buttons selected

Comment: when some other radio button(which is not disabled) is clicked. the selection changes.

Comment: look at my second comment above. you have to disable the whole group if you have a disabled button

Comment: i can't do that .. this is my requirement .. a disabled radio button mean something else in my ui.(I understand the foolishness in this arguement but this is the functionality i want)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two other answers are so far not handling radio groups.

I made that work after a battle with an issue with the **is()**

EITHER I had a syntax error in ***is(":checked")*** OR jQuery does not return true for a disabled, but checked radio - if the click on the other radio temporarily removes the checked javascript boolean from the other radio without actually removing the checked attribute, that would explain it.

**WORKING EXAMPLE**

*Short version:* cannot handle more than one disabled

```
$("#container :radio").click(function(e){
    var disR = $("#container input[name="+$(this).attr("name")+"]")
     .filter(":disabled");
    if (disR.length > 0 && disR.attr("checked")==="checked") {
          e.preventDefault();
          return false
    }
});
```

*Longer version*: - now it is getting more and more interesting to wrap each radio group and use the other suggestion

http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/HQs6s/

```
$("#container :radio").click(function(e){
    var radioGroup = $("#container input[name="+$(this).attr("name")+"]");
    var disR = radioGroup.filter(":disabled"); // cannot use :checked
    if (disR.length == 0) return true;
    for (var i=0,n=disR.length, chk;i<n;i++) {
        chk = disR[i].getAttribute("checked");
        if (chk && chk==="checked") { // html element
          e.preventDefault();
          return false;
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: Note that `disR.length > 0` implies `disR` is one *or more* elements. In case of more than one elements, the `.attr()` will return the attribute value for the first element, which may or may not be checked so better check `checked=checked` for all matching disabled elements.

Comment: @Sal Fixed, but now no longer interesting compared to yours and Niklas'

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
$('#container :radio:checked:disabled').parent().delegate(":radio","click",function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/dTBVa/50/

Comment: Did not work when the disabled attribute was removed via jQuery.

Comment: @Salman nowhere did he state that the disabled attributes would be removed, but if thats the case, he can just unbind on those events this event, and bind a new one of these.

Comment: Looks clever. I like it :) Now make it work for a radio group, please

Comment: @mplungjan `$('input:radio[name="foo"]:checked:disabled').parent().delegate(":radio","click",function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
});` http://jsfiddle.net/dTBVa/66/

Comment: No. That does it for one named radio. I want for all groups to disallow clicks if ONE radio in their respective group is checked AND disabled from the server.

Comment: @mplungjan please define group then, because radio buttons are grouped by their `name`.

Comment: @Niklas Yes - my radio groups are radios named the same. Please see my answer and my fiddle. It now works the way I believe the OP wants

Comment: @mplungjan If he intends to have multiple groups (he defined in his question *a group*) he can just apply each of the radio groups in their own container, and apply that code to each container. For example changing the #container into a .container and the code to `$('.container :radio:checked:disabled').parent().delegate(":radio","click",function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
});` and he'll get far more done with lot less code.

Comment: @Nik I am not convinced. Also why delegate all the time? It is confusing since "this" no longer returns the clicked radio but the container it seems

Comment: @mplungjan As he uses delegate himself. If the markup isn't there on DOM load for example. It doesn't need the reference to `this`, as it is already performing the task it needs within the selectors.

Comment: @Nik did you look at my fiddle? Is there anything inherently wrong with my approach? I do not like to have to bend over backwards to get jQuery to do what I mean. For example have to wrap my radios in their own container

Comment: @mplungjan I did. Don't get me wrong, I don't think your approach is wrong by any means, but if it is limited to 1 group or if the groups are wrapped inside anything, the same result can be obtained with my solution with far less code. Keep in mind you wouldn't have to go head over heels to wrap each of them in something. If you have your form inside a table, you could reference the cells, if it was in a dd/dt wrapper, you could do the same. The only problem arises if you put all your radio buttons one after another without any sort of containers, which I personally feel is far less a probabil

Comment: If I need to handle more than one disabled radio, then the code becomes too big an your suggestion looks the simplest again

Answer (score 1):

Inside the click event: `$(":checked")` points to the radio that was clicked, not the one that checked. `preventDefault()` determines whether the clicked radio will stay clicked or not. So you might want to do something like this:

```
function attachMyNoClick() {
    if ($("#container :radio").filter(":checked").is(":disabled")) {
        $("#container :radio").bind("click.MyNoClick", false);
    }
    else {
        $("#container :radio").unbind("click.MyNoClick");
    }
}    
$(document).ready(function() {
    attachMyNoClick
});
```

If there is jQuery code that changes the disabled state of radio buttons, you should hook the above function inside that function. You must first `unbind()` the click event then `bind()` the click event if necessary.

## [Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/dTBVa/62/)

Note: disabled radio buttons will not submit even if they are checked.

Comment: @Salman - does this handle a GROUP? Don't you need a test for the name being the same as the clicked? What does click.MyNoClick refer to? I made a start here http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/HQs6s/ but it did not do what I wanted

Comment: @mplungjan: No it does not check for a group (because I was being lazy :) but you can modify the selectors a little like so `$("#container input[name=foo]")` or something similar.

Comment: @mplungjan: `click.MyNoClick` creates a namespace for events. Say sometime later you attach another `.click()` event to the same elements and then try to remove the `.click()` event that prevents default. Without namespace you'll end up writing `.unbind('click')` which removes all click handles, not just the one you want to remove.

Comment: @mplungjan: about your fiddle, paste this code in console and note the output: `if($("#i-dont-exist")){alert("i-dont-exist exists! [wrong]")} if($("#i-dont-exist").length){alert("i-dont-exist exists! [correct]")}`. The thing to note is that you must use `.length` to determine whether jQuery found something or not. `if([/*empty array*/])` will evaluate as true even when the array is empty.

Comment: Please see my [fiddle now](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/HQs6s/) - the logic is close I think, I just never can figure out when to use this or $(this): if ($("#container input[name="+$(this).attr("name")+"]")
        .filter(":disabled")[0]
        .is(":checked"))

Comment: @mplun: you dont need `[0]` and most importantly, read 1st few lines of my answer: inside the event the `:checked` will return the radio you just clicked, not the one that was checked before clicking. In your fiddle, the `.filter(":disabled").is(":checked")` will always return false because the disabled element will not be checked during the event, it will be the 1/2/4 radio that will be checked. After the event is processed, the clicked element will be checked or not depending on whether `preventDefault()` was called or not. See the revised demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/HQs6s/13/).

Comment: @Sal I want to check in the clicked radio if there is another disabled and checked radio which has the same name as the clicked one. So if the radio is checked AND disabled at the server, it will show checked and disabled and none of the other non-disabled in the SAME group can be checked. I think we are not on the same page of what login the OP wants.

Comment: @mplun: back to the basics -- iterate all radio *groups* on `$(document).ready()` and assign a `preventsDefault()` function to entire radio group if the checked radio is also disabled. You cannot check this condition from within the click event because the checked property is momentarily altered during the click event.

Comment: @Sal I believe I have found the solution. Please see my answer.

Comment: @Sal are you saying that the is(":checked") fails because it is removed from the disabled box when the click is made on another box?

Comment: @Sal Thanks - quite weird chain of events. The attribute is visible, but the checked is false.